# Show that UV is a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices of the same size. Show that $UV$ is a unitary matrix.

I looked up the definition for unitary matrices in my notes. It says that A matrix is unitary if $UU^*= I$. I'm guessing that I have to follow something along the lines of:

$$(UV)(U^* V^*)$$

Then I'm guessing I would use the associative property to get

$$(UU^*)(VV^*)$$

And we are given that U and V is unitary so it would turn into

$$(I)(I) = I^2$$

Which is the same thing as I because I is a projection matrix. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I guess $(UV)^*=V^*U^*$

Comment: Okay so then it would be (UV)(UV)* which would become UVV*U* = U(VV*)U* = U(I)U* = (UU*)(I) = (I)(I) = $I^2$ = I (by projection matrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix $U$ is unitary if its Hermitian adjoint $U^*$ is its inverse. That is, $U$ is by definition unitary if its Hermitian adjoint satisfies $U^* = U^{-1}$. Recall that the Hermitian adjoint is the complex conjugate of the transpose, so when you take the Hermitian adjoint of a product, it is the product of the adjoints in the reverse order:
$$(UV)^* = V^* U^*.$$
The reason that order is reversed is due to transposition.

Thus, when $U$ and $V$ are unitary, 
$$(UV)(UV)^* = (UV)(V^*U^*)=UIU^* = UU^* = I,$$
and likewise
$$(UV)^*(UV) = (V^*U^*)(UV)=V^*IV = V^*V = I.$$
So indeed $(UV)^* = (UV)^{-1},$ and thus $UV$ is unitary.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have the right idea. A *unitary matrix* is a matrix $X$ that satisfies $XX^*=X^*X=I$ where $(-)^*$ is the conjugate-transpose operator. Note that $(XY)^*=Y^*X^*$.

Now, if $U$ and $V$ are unitary, then
\begin{align*}
(UV)(UV)^* &= (UV)(V^*U^*) & (UV)^*(UV) &= (V^*U^*)(UV) \\
&= U(VV^*)U^* & &= V^*(U^*U)V \\
&= UIU^* &&= V^*IV \\
&= UU^* &&= V^*V \\
&= I &&= I
\end{align*}
Hence $UV$ is also unitary.

Note that this fact helps establish the existence of the *[unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group)* $U(n)$ as a subgroup of the *[general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group)* $\DeclareMathOperator{GL}{GL}\GL(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

A square matrix $U$ is unitary **iff** it is an isometry.

Hence $\|UVx\| = \|Vx\| = \|x\|$, and so $UV$ is unitary.