# Is a Superposition of Unitary Operators also Unitary?

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is simple: under what conditions is a linear superposition of unitary operators also unitary?

Comment: Do you mean a linear combination?

Comment: @J.G.: OP might be asking if $UV$ is unitary if $U$ and $V$ are both unitary.  Perhaps see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288758/show-that-uv-is-a-unitary-matrix

Comment: I am aware that $UV$ is unitary because unitary matrices form a group, for example, I was just curious as to when a linear sum of two unitary matrices would also be unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two operators $U_1,U_2$ and constants $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, we have

$$
(\alpha U_1+\beta U_2)^*=\overline\alpha U_1^*+\overline\beta U_2^*
$$
and 
$$
(\alpha U_1+\beta U_2)^*(\alpha U_1+\beta U_2)=(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)I+
\overline\alpha\beta U_1^*U_2+\alpha\overline\beta U_1U_2^*
$$
Which you want to be the identity. It would be sufficient to ask for $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ and $\alpha \overline\beta U_1^*U_2$ to be skew Hermitian.

Comment: So essentially for a sum of unitary operators to be unitary you have to impose some kind of normalisation condition?

Comment: Also there is another arbitrary condition which you have to specify so it looks as if the sum in general is not going to be unitary.

Comment: It seems that way, but as you can see above, a normalization condition isn't enough because of second term. This makes some sense, we are dealing with an algebra (we care about how these things multiply), not just a normed linear space, so more than just staying on the unit ball is not enough

Comment: Why is it sufficient for the product you mention to be skew Hermitian?  Is the idea that taking the conjugate of $\alpha \bar{\beta} U_1 U^*_2 = - \bar{\alpha} \beta U^*_1 U_2$, but don't you still have to take the transpose?  *Edit* Now I see now, the $*$ is the adjoint, which is the conjugate transpose, so you take conjugates of the coefficients, put on a minus sign and switch the symbols for the adjoints.

Answer (score 1):

If $U,\,V$ are unitary so is $UV$, viz. $(UV)^\dagger UV=V^\dagger U^\dagger UV=V^\dagger V=I$. However, in general $aU+bV$ won't be for constants $a,\,b$, even if we impose a normalisation condition on them. Consider e.g. the case $a=b,\,V=-U$.